# Mongoose restore previous revision

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I increase the '__v'-property of my mongoose-schema using the mongoose-middleware

```
contractSchema.pre("findOneAndUpdate", function (next) {
  this.update({}, { $inc: { __v: 1 } }, next);
})
```

As i just realised this then overwrite the existing document and does not save it separatly. What I need is to save all previous versions of the table so i can get each previous version individually, is this possible using the middleware?

Comment: Hi @Kevin, have you found any solution for this? because I'm also facing this issue nd unable to got any solution

Comment: @vivek more or less yes. I use mongoose-middleware and before the .save is executed I create a new instance of the Schema-Object and save the previous version of the document then within the given collection manually. More here: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html